# En Java, ¿cómo borrar texto entre dos delimitadores, incluyendo todo, incluso los delimitadores?

Tags: java, regex, buenas-prácticas

En una cadena tengo mucha cantidad de texto, y parte de ese texto se encuentra entre los delimitadores `[rubrica]` y `[/rubrica]`.

Estoy usando `replaceAll` con este patrón: `(?s)[rubrica].*?/rubrica]` adaptado de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29381093/5587982), y casi me funciona, sólo que no me elimina el carácter de apertura `[`.

Por ejemplo:

```
String s="[rubrica]<p>Texto a eliminar... 123 *_[...] Lorem ipsum</p> [/rubrica]<p>...Texto a \"guardar\".</p> <p>[...] Lorem ipsum</p>"; 
s=s.replaceAll("(?s)[rubrica].*?/rubrica]", "");
System.out.println(s);
```

La salida de este código es:

```
[<p>...Texto a "guardar".</p> <p>[...] Lorem ipsum</p>
```

Como ven, no desaparece el `[`.

¿Cómo debo corregir mi REGEX? ¿O puedo hacerlo de una forma más óptima?

**PD:** La idea es eliminar de la forma **menos costosa** todo lo que haya entre `[rubrica]` y `[/rubrica]` **inclusive**. Y, no quiero tener que coger un avión para comprar el pan :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escapa el `[` con dos `\\` ya que `[` es un caracter especial y no lo puedes usar como los demás. La expresión regular quedaría así:

```
"(?s)[\\[rubrica].*?/rubrica]"
```

El código que tienes quedaría casi igual:

```
String s="[rubrica]<p>Texto a eliminar... 123 *_[...] Lorem ipsum</p> [/rubrica]<p>...Texto a \"guardar\".</p> <p>[...] Lorem ipsum</p>";
s=s.replaceAll("(?s)[\\[rubrica].*?/rubrica]", "");
System.out.println(s);
```

La salida es esta:

```
<p>...Texto a "guardar".</p> <p>[...] Lorem ipsum</p>
```

Comment: Excelente, funciona de la forma esperada. Muchísimas gracias.